# Routing: prefix item name before controller resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to get the following routes to work in my Rails 3 app.

**Scenario**:
I have the following controllers in my app:

- Practices
- Doctors
- Patients
- Prescriptions

Putting up :resources for each of them in routes.rb gives me routes from

- example.com/practices
- example.com/doctors/1/edit etc

What I'd like to have however is the following resourceful routes, for example:

- **example.com/james_practice/docs** that translates to the doctors controller
- **example.com/james_practice/awesome_prescriptions** that routes to the prescriptions controller etc. etc.
  both of these giving me access to *:practice* name and furthermore route the correct controller with all the helpers like edit_docs_path(doctor) etc.

How would I go about this? I've used

```
resources :prescriptions, :path => "/:practice/awesome_prescriptions"
```

but although it showed the correct routes in "rake routes", it still wouldn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the route you're looking for:

```
scope :path => ":practice" do
  resources :docs, :controller => "doctors"
  resources :awesome_prescriptions, :controller => "prescriptions"
end
```

By the way, you didn't give me the example of `Patients`, so I didn't put it there.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I meant. "scope :path" seems to be the magic I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

map.resources is just a pattern, more like a shortcut. If you want to have URLs like in your examples you should use "named routes". A good screencast for Rails 2.x: http://railscasts.com/episodes/34-named-routes

Edit: Read section 3.2 in Rails Tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

p.s. Also you'll face a case where people use "." in their names and it'll cause problems. 
Here's my route for "tags"

`map.resources :tags, :requirements => { :id => %r([^/;,?]+) }`

Comment: I've tried going the named routes way. But this would mean that I'd have to write out every single use case for that route, including all put/delete etc requests for every controller?